# What were Argentina's intentions for the Falkland Islanders?

Tags: argentina, falklands-war

Argentina must have assumed in 1982 that its occupation of the Falkland Islands (Malvinas) would be successful and that Argentinian sovereignty over the territory would be accepted. What were the Argentinians' intentions for the local population?

Did they expect to grant the local population the right to continue living there?

Were the Falklanders immediately in April 1982 (or were they going to be) classed as citizens of Argentina or resident aliens or was some kind of special title given to them?

The official name would have been the Malvinas of course. But were they planning to be relaxed about the name at all? Would locals have been allowed to carry on calling it the Falklands, whatever the official name? Such as in English language newspapers?

Were there to be forced deportations of the local population on any scale? Were there plans to settle the territories systematically with Argentinians?

Comment: @Luke, do you think that poetry is nearer to the truth than history? If so don't confuse the latter with the former, otherwise you risk of not to understand what politic is.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mean it as a political rant( again im sorry if i come off with a tone like that). Im just wanting to know what wouldve been the outcome of the falkland war for the locals(like in anyother war) and if any had an idea what would change of in the next one( i know that speculationand no one needs to aswer that, but what of the first one?)

Comment: Also "imperialist Britain" is part of the lyrics to the song, not my perosnal opinion, just to clarify

Comment: @Valthersus, I don't think that Luke was talking about your question as it sounds legitimate, but rather Carlo_R's statement about Margaret Thatcher in the comments.

Comment: Could we focus this question on history? This strikes me as a better fit for politics, or world affairs or something.

Comment: But this was history, the falklands was occupied by argentina, so what was their plan?  I cant find any where a crumb of their plans, unless its all writen in spanish!

Comment: I dont understand how this was not a real question or is history everything before ww2

Comment: I for one would be interested in seeing the answer to this. And it is history. Thatcher's even dead!

Comment: @Valthersus i've rewritten your question and nominated it for reopening. if it's too different for you, then let me know and/or roll it back

Comment: I like the edits, imo they should allow the question to be answered while focusing it onto a historical, rather than political subject.

Comment: @hawbsl Nice job.

Comment: How did Argentina expect to not get squashed by Britain and its allies is the real question. We could have laughed them off the island.

Comment: It's not that they didn't expect to get squashed by Britain; IIRC (and paraphrasing here of course) they didn't expect Britain to even _notice_

Answer (score 15):

In the 74 days that Argentina occupied the Falkland Islands several people were at first deported and then placed under house arrest at Fox Bay East. Governor Rex Hunt was removed from the islands the day of his surrender:

> I refused to shake hands with him and said: "You have landed
> unlawfully on British territory and I order you to remove yourself and
> your troops forthwith."
>
> He said: "We have taken back what is rightfully ours and we shall stay
> forever."
>
> I had to get out by 4.30 that afternoon. We were flown to Montevideo.
>
> Governor Hunt - [BBC Article, 2002](http://news.bbc.co.uk/hi/english/static/in_depth/uk/2002/falklands/my_story/hunt.stm)

As were other Falkland Islanders, such as Bill Luxton and David Colville, who were identified by Argentinian Military Police as being potential troublemakers as they were known to be publicly critical of Argentina.

In fact, the deportation of David Colville indicates that the Argentinians might not have allowed the continued use of the Falklands name by papers as at the time of the invasion he was the editor/owner of The Falklands Times.([David Colville's final Falklands War episode](http://www.holdthefrontpage.co.uk/2007/news/david-colville-s-final-falklands-war-episode/), June 2007)

It appears that 13 people were deported from the Falkland Islands immediately following the invasion, followed by the 29 Royal Marines. While others were placed under house arrest.

> **April 5th**
> The Argentine occupation forces have imposed strict military rule
> …The Islanders are under house arrest until further notice, and anyone
> defying this order is threatened with immediate imprisonment. … Other
> penalties have been imposed in the face of growing hostility from the
> Islanders. These include 30 days in prison for rude gestures against
> the military, 60 days for irreverence to the Argentine flag… Messages
> from radio hams … say that troops are searching homes and confiscating
> equipment.
>
> **April 13th**
> A party of 13 civil servants, including the Chief of Police, the
> Registrar General and the Chief Secretary, are deported from the
> Falklands. Executive Council member, Bill Luxton, and his wife, are
> also deported by ‘Chief of Police’ Patricio Dowling for ‘political
> reasons.’
>
> **April 28th**
>
> 14 Islanders, deemed ‘troublemakers’ are detained at Fox
> Bay East.
>
> [The Falkland Islands History and Timeline](http://falklandstimeline.wordpress.com/1982-2/)

It is known that in the short period of occupation that Argentines did make many changes consistent with plans to completely change the islands to be fully part of Argentina. Spanish was made the official language, Port Stanley was renamed Puerto Argentino, Falklands stamps were franked over with Argentine post codes/post marks, traffic was changed to drive on the right, signs were changed over to be in Spanish and use the metric system and the peso replaced the Falklands Pound.

Martin Middlebrook in his book *The Argentine Fight For The Falklands.*, along with numerous other sources, states that Argentina planned to and did, for the most part, treat Islanders with respect and prevented the taking of their food, homes and other possessions but whether this indicates that they planned to allow them to stay or to force deportation I do not know. However, given all the changes described in the paragraph above it does appear that the Argentine's, to some extent, did intend on their being Argentinian settlers on the islands.

Comment: I will add here that I'm sure that I read somewhere about Argentina's overall plans for the islands - but I can't for the life of me remember where. If I remember, I'll edit to add the information.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0094JTQE4 is an excellent source on the Falklands war.

Comment: Neat trick pulled by the Argentinians, to first deport, and then place under house arrest, suspect individuals. Mere mortals have to be satisfied with performing the feats the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, it's worded funny; the first round were deported. Eventually, people were put under house arrest when deportation wasn't practical.

Comment: Was so interested by this as David Colville is my uncle. I would like to point out that he rang my grandparents to tell them they were invading and my grandmother called 10 downing street and they brushed it off. This was two weeks before military action started. Shame on Thatcher.

Comment: LOL didn't read his answer below! this is just what my mum told me anyway. didn't get the stories from him.

Answer (score 13):

Hahahahaha Yes!!! I didn't have much choice re deportation. The Argentine top brass said I was being booted out because of (allegedly)  printing Anti-Argentine propaganda over the years.

Huh! Not true. I still remember that morning three weeks after the invasion when a couple of soldiers came to my flat and told me I had 30 minutes to pack my stuff and get to the airport!

Still cannot believe it's THIRTY-FIVE years ago

```
Best wishes to you all... 
Dave Colville 
Former owner/ed of the Falkland Islands Times
```

Comment: Now that's a source!

Comment: Yes, it isn't often we can get first-hand answers to legitimate history questions here. Thank you for this.